# An error ocurred while starting the kernel (spyder in anaconda)

Tags: spyder

When I start spyder from anaconda this error shows in it

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py",
>   line 528, in get value = obj._trait_values[self.name] KeyError:
>   'context'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole.py", line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 261, in start_kernel
self._connect_control_socket()
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 210, in _connect_control_socket
self._control_socket = self._create_connected_socket('control')
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 543, in _create_connected_socket
sock = self.context.socket(socket_type)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
return self.get(obj, cls)
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 535, in get
value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 42, in _context_default
return zmq.Context()
File "zmq/backend/cython/context.pyx", line 49, in zmq.backend.cython.context.Context.__cinit__
zmq.error.ZMQError: Bad address
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the copy of the [thread](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7378), maybe some antivirus/firewall is blocking. Try to disable that and see if that works.